# Getting an error comparing Last Logon time with a Date

Tags: powershell

I have a script written that will get all of the logons for all of the users on a machine and filter out anything over 30 days old. We want to use it for more accurate count of some licenses that we pay a per user rate on. The script also filter out the Admin accounts we use along with the System and Service account.

This is the script.

```
#This script will check which users have logged on in the last X days
#Set Variables
#Change the number in the parenthesis after adddays to change how far back to filter
#example (get-date).adddays(-30) gets all logins for the last 30 days from     today (-60) would be the last 60 days

$AuditDate = (get-date).adddays(-30)
$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$CurrentDate = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d"

#Delete any previously created files
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\PowerShellScripts\LastLogon" -Recurse |
Where-Object CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-0) | Remove-Item - ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#The Login Profile is filtered here
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_NetworkLoginProfile | 
Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.FullName -notlike "*Agvance*"} | 
Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.FullName -notlike "*Sophos*"} |
Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.FullName -notlike "*SSI*"} |
Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.FullName -ne "AgvAdmin"} |
Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.FullName -ne ""} | 
Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Name -notlike "*SYSTEM*"} |
Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Name -notlike "*SERVICE*"} |
Where-Object -FilterScript {($_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastLogon)) -ge $AuditDate} | 
Select-Object  Name,@{label='LastLogon';expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastLogon)}} | Export-Csv    C:\PowerShellScripts\LastLogon.csv -NoTypeInformation

#The user count is created here
$number = (Import-Csv C:\PowerShellScripts\LastLogon.csv | measure | % {    $_.Count})

#The file is renamed to include computername, date, and user count
rename-item -path C:\PowerShellScripts\LastLogon.csv -NewName 
C:\PowerShellScripts\LastLogon-$ComputerName-$CurrentDate-UserCount-$number.csv
```

The script works as intended but when it is run I receive this error.

```
Exception calling "ConvertToDateTime" with "1" argument(s): "Exception    calling "ToDateTime" with "1" argument(s): "Specified 
argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: dmtfDate""
At C:\Agvance Updates\LastLogon.ps1:22 char:29
+ Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastLogon) -ge $AuditDate} |
+                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptMethodRuntimeException
```

I have tried to different ways of comparing the $*.ConvertToDateTime($*.LastLogon) and the $AuditDate. This way works but I would like to get rid of the error with the $*.ConvertToDateTime($*.LastLogon). Is there a better way to get this date and compare it for the filtering?

Comment: Just for efficiency - wouldn't a single -notmatch combining all the tests with `$_.FullName` speed things up? `Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.FullName -notmatch 'Agvance|Sophos|SSI|^AgvAdmin$|^$'}
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LastLogon` might be empty, and `ConvertToDateTime()` doesn't accept empty values.

To exclude those entries with no value for `LastLogon` (if, for example, the profile was never logged on to), try:

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_NetworkLoginProfile | 
[...]
Where-Object -FilterScript {![System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.LastLogon)} |
Where-Object -FilterScript {($_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastLogon)) -ge $AuditDate} |
[...]
```